# Android Jetpack Compose Wrap Content like (Word / Absolute Position)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I’m not sure what I’m wanting to do actually can be done, but wanted to see if there are thoughts on how to go about solving this.

Conceptually, I have an Image or some other piece of content that should be positioned in a container. A Surface or a Layout isn’t important specifically (Image below shows the concept layout I’m focusing on at this time). What I would like to achieve is 2 fold.

If the `Header` extends the length of the container and enters within `16.dp` of `Circle` in the top right it should break to the next line and continue on. However, if the next line or subsequent lines match this length or are able to go further as long as they are (some number: `16.dp`??) below the `Circle` they will continue on filling the container. The first part is simple with a `Row` or `Box` that has limited width. But I can’t fathom how to conceptually break up the `Header` or get measurements for the parts. Maybe if I split the string…?? (In this case it will always be a string.)

The second part is the `Box` with dotted lines. This is content (`(@Composable () -> Unit)?`) that I will have no control over what goes inside personally. What I would like to be able to do is determine similar to above, but with `Any?` content. What I can’t figure out here is a structure or access to `Placeable?` that allows me to measure each element in the `Box` container without limiting the whole `Box` at one time. Ideally I would limit each element inside. I would also be open to maybe providing something that would allow someone else to do this work so they can determine the best solution, but I’m not entirely sure how that would look either.

`Code` below for current approach.

[image: Example: Showing a bolded title with the text “Header” and a Circle shape in the top right corner that is a gray color. A box with dotted lines is below the header title, but does not fill the container. This box stops before it gets too close to the circle.]

Code::

Currently I’m using a `Layout` wrapped by a `Surface`. I measure each piece and adjust the layout here. Placing is similar to how `CoreTextField` handles layout. But I seem to be limited to just the top level `measureable`. Maybe I’m not digging deep enough?

```
Layout(content) { measureables,constraints ->
    
    …

    val spotPlaceable =
            measureables.find { it.layoutId == CardLayoutContent.Spot }?.measure(looseConstraints)
        spotPlaceable?.let {
            layoutHeight += spotYOffset
        }
        layoutHeight += heightOrZero(spotPlaceable)

    …
```